# pip install can't find certain version of a package while I can find it on pypi

Tags: pip, pypi

I'm trying to install `tensorboard==2.12.0` through pip install but it keeps telling me

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard==2.12.0 (from versions: 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.11.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorboard==2.12.0
```

But I can see the latest version is `2.12.0` on pypi from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/), am I doing something wrong?

I tried `pip install tensorboard==2.12.0`, I also tried to change my requirements.txt file to include `tensorboard==2.12.0` and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the list of available versions I guess you use Python 3.7. `tensorboard==2.12` requires Python 3.8+.

Comment: Thank you, I just found that out too.